# magento1.9 add 5% tax to subtotal and shipping price

Tags: magento-1.9, tax

I have added a new rule 5%(on product and shipping) for customers who are UAE.

Please find the below screenshots

[image]

Tax Rule:

[image]

And Tax settings:

[image]

**Note: All products in the site Tax class is: Shipping**

Frontend issue is:

[image]

Product price is AED 1400

Product 5% tax is AED 70

Shipping price is AED 22.20

Shipping 5% tax is AED 1.11

Total should be AED 1493.31

But tax is adding double and result is AED 1,564.42

Please help me how to fix this issue

thanks

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create tax classes and assign to products by following link :

https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/how-create-tax-rule-magento

than you can set tax for shipping price using below configuration :

**System > Configuration > Sales > Tax > calculation settings**

Comment: yes i did the same but here iam getting a issue https://prnt.sc/hsfpyf tax is being added twice

Comment: @Raghu please edit the question with the proper issue , also check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933571/magento-tax-calculation-suddenly-calcaluted-twice) once.....

Comment: ok sure i will edit the question with full details thanks

Comment: hi @Baby in Magento i have edited the question, can you please check this

Comment: @Raghu did you checked this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933571/magento-tax-calculation-suddenly-calcaluted-twice ?

Comment: yes Set Tax Calculation Based On to Shipping Origin. after this same issue exists in the site

Comment: @Raghu check [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27537274/magento-tax-issue-tax-being-applied-twice) ,  [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26449406/magento-applying-tax-twice) , [link4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23774844/magento-tax-calculation-added-twice-on-cart-page) & [link6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17590364/magento-applying-tax-vat-twice) , if these dont work then try create new tax rule and rates and apply to products, also flush cache and do reindex once......

Answer (score 0):

Remove var/cache , var/session directory's and run browser in incognito mode. And also you can reindex your data from admin menu 
I think it will help to you.